# Regarding USB hosting on android to a DSLR

Tags: android, usb

Can I check with you guys if I wanna create an app that can connect to a camera like to control the camera like for example to take photos, connection via OTG usb between 2 device do i need to program something like a driver for the camera to phone in order for them to communicate? If is require is are you able to recommend me some software or method how to? or is there any guide or documentation? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a program it with drivers that would recognize the camera as like a web cam is on a computer. Same concept in my opinion. Just a little more limited on a cell phone but im sure that its possible. More than likely it will require rooting your devise.

Comment: thanks for the reply but do you know of anywhere I can read abt it? like how to write a driver for my android device to the camera? and I saw on some links states that ICS had enable usb hosting so I need not root my phone to use the usb hosting functionality is it correct?

Comment: [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/94991/dslr-controller-enables-android-based-canon-camera-control/) I found this...very very very similar to what i think your trying to do.

Comment: haha yup this is something I need to do for my project so I trying to look for ways to do it :)